# Nested wxSizers; stacking panel vertically wrapping content

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

[image]

This is a reference layout (colors only for highlighting the bounds) I created using HTML and CSS. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .message {
                padding: 5px;
                background-color: red;
            }

            .text-field {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 5px;
                background-color: gray;
                color: black;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .max-size {
                max-width: 60%;
            }

            .align-right {
                text-align: right;
            }

            .align-right p {
                text-align: left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="message">
            <div class="msg-header">
                <p class="text-field max-size">Sender</p>
            </div>
            <div class="msg-content">
                <p class="text-field max-size">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <div class="msg-header align-right">
                <p class="text-field max-size">You</p>
            </div>
            <div class="msg-content align-right">
                <p class="text-field max-size">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I try to achieve the same layout using c++ and wxWidgets. Ignoring the 60% max size I tried the following.

```
MainFrame::MainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size) {
    this->InitialiseComponents();
}

void MainFrame::InitialiseComponents() {
    ...

    this->panelChat = new wxScrolledWindow(this->splitterChatLog, MFID_LIST_BOX_CHAT, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(850, 100));
    this->panelChat->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 255, 255));
    this->panelChat->SetScrollRate(5, 5);
    this->sizerChat = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    this->panelChat->SetSizer(this->sizerChat);

    ...
}

void MainFrame::AddChatMessage(std::string addr, std::string str, bool sent) {
    wxPanel *panelMsg = new wxPanel(this->panelChat, wxID_ANY);
    panelMsg->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 0, 0));

    wxStaticText *textAddr = new wxStaticText(panelMsg, wxID_ANY, addr);
    wxStaticText *textMsg = new wxStaticText(panelMsg, wxID_ANY, str);

    wxBoxSizer *sizerMsgHeader = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxBoxSizer *sizerMsgContent = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    
    sizerMsgHeader->Add(textAddr, 0, (sent ? wxALIGN_RIGHT : 0));
    sizerMsgContent->Add(textMsg, 0, (sent ? wxALIGN_RIGHT : 0));

    wxBoxSizer *sizerMsg = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    sizerMsg->Add(sizerMsgHeader, 0, wxEXPAND);
    sizerMsg->Add(sizerMsgContent, 0, wxEXPAND | wxBOTTOM, 5);
    panelMsg->SetSizer(sizerMsg);
    this->sizerChat->Add(panelMsg, 0, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT | wxTOP | wxRIGHT, 5);
}
```

The problems are:

1. Calling AddChatMessage multiple times does not stack the messages they lay on top of each other.
2. Each message panel is a 20x20 red square. It's neither expanding horizontally nor wrapping its content.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add a call to `Layout();` or `panelChat->Layout();` at the end of the `MainFrame::AddChatMessage` method.  This will force the panelChat window to rearrange all its children according to the sizer flags given to it when the children were added.

However, wxWidgets does offer the [wxWebView](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html) control.  If you already have a chatlog in html format, using that control might be the best way to display it.

---

You can restrict the text area to 60% on the right or left of the chat window.  One way to do this is to use a flexible spacer set to take up 40% of the width and set the message panel to take up the remaining 60%.  I think this version of the `AddChatMessage` should do that.

```
void MainFrame::AddChatMessage(std::string addr, std::string str, bool sent) {
    wxPanel *panelMsg = new wxPanel(this->panelChat, wxID_ANY);
    panelMsg->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(255, 0, 0));

    wxStaticText *textAddr = new wxStaticText(panelMsg, wxID_ANY, addr);
    wxStaticText *textMsg = new wxStaticText(panelMsg, wxID_ANY, str);
    textMsg->Wrap(60 * GetClientSize().GetWidth() / 100);

    wxBoxSizer *sizerMsg = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    sizerMsg->Add(textAddr, 0, (sent ? wxALIGN_RIGHT : 0));
    sizerMsg->Add(textMsg, 0, (sent ? wxALIGN_RIGHT : 0));

    panelMsg->SetSizer(sizerMsg);

    // Create a new horizontal sizer and add a spacer either before or after
    // taking up 40% of the horizontal space.
    wxBoxSizer* newChatSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    if ( sent )
    {
        newChatSizer->AddStretchSpacer(2);
    }
    newChatSizer->Add(panelMsg, 3, wxEXPAND);
    if ( !sent )
    {
        newChatSizer->AddStretchSpacer(2);
    }
    this->sizerChat->Add(newChatSizer, 0, wxEXPAND | wxLEFT | wxTOP | wxRIGHT, 5);

    panelChat->Layout();
}
```

In this case this adds a space (either on the left or right) with a proportion of 2.  The the message panel is added with a proportion of 3.  Since the total proportion is 5, the spacer is given 2/5=40% of the space leaving the remainging 60% of the space for the message.

Note: I also removed the `textAddr` and `textMsg` sizers and instead just added the static texts to the `sizerMsg`.  Usually a sizer containing only one item isn't necessary, and I didn't see what those two sizers were doing.

Comment: Okay, and do you know how to achieve the 60% max-width using wxWidgets? Also, I only created this HTML example to have something to know how the result would look like because I'm more familiar with HTML than with wxWidgets. There is no actual chatlog I could load. The only way would be to pass a string containing a generated HTML document like above to the web view if this is possible.

Comment: I tried to do it manually using the resize event but when I add this event using `Bind` the UI gets invisible...

Comment: Comment to edit: The `panelChat` is actually a `wxScrolledWindow`, vertical only. I don't know if this makes a difference but the static text does not wrap when exceeding 60%. Not even at 100%.

Comment: I think you need to call the `Wrap` method on the static text to get it to wrap.  I've edited the answer to show how to do this.  However, it doesn't look like the wrap can be changed after it is set, so I think if you want to rewrap whenever the main form is resized, you'll need to recreate the entire chat with the so that the texts can be given the new wrap value.

Comment: The problem with the wrap is that this is no display property but it changes the actual data set (the label) by inserting line breaks. So calling wrap when shrinking, changes the label again by inserting line breaks again which misshapes the label more and more. When growing, wrap changes nothing because the text fits...

Comment: Ultimately, I don't think a static text will be adequate for this kind of chat log.  Is this just a programing exercise or is this the beginnings of an actual application?  For an actual application, I think the best way to present a chat log is either with wxWebview or by writing a custom widget.

Comment: This is an actual application for university but I'm more or less limited to c++ since I have to use c++ for communication over a UART interface. I already asked if the webview can receive pure HTML to display or if I have to specify a URL to load from.

Comment: With wxWebview you can load HTML stored in a wxString variable with the SetPage method.  There's also the option to create a [memory file system](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_memory_f_s_handler.html) so that you can store the css/js/image in separate memory files instead of directly in the html file.  Unfortunately on windows, the memory file system can't be used with the webview_edge backend yet, but it can be used with the older ie backend. I think the webview sample shows in more detail how to use the memory file system.

Comment: Relatively recent versions of wxWidgets also have the RunScript method that you could use to add messages to the chatlog as they come in instead of reloading the entire page.  Unfortunately I don't know enough js to give an example.